# How to clean output folder before build using Brunch.io

Tags: brunch

I'm using brunch.io and it works great.

The only thing I don't know how to achieve is to have a clean before build.

For example, if I `brunch build` it creates source maps. If I do `brunch build --production` it doesn't create source maps.  However, the source maps that were already there are not deleted.

Is there any option / plugin to clean? Should I use npm clean in some other place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a clean pass, I would suggest to just remove the `public` directory.

`rm -rf public/ && brunch build -P`

You can add it to `package.json` like that:

`"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf public/ && brunch build -P"
},`

and then just do `npm run build` instead of `brunch build -P`

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/before-brunch to run any commands before brunch build.